# Is it possible to build a high-end static website completely using visual studio 2010 express?

Tags: php, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to build a static website on my own with having a 10% of knowledge in web development. Please suggest me the best method to develop?

tools required ? (something like drag n drops widget)

P.S I don't want any tutorial. I would like to learn and develop on my own and also I have not mentioned some basic hello world website. Do I wanted to build some high-end static website!

Some one please suggest me the right path?

Comment: Y do some people downvoting my question? Is there anything wrong in my question? if so, please post a comment so that could be a chance for me to learn and correct myself going forward.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thx Quintin Balsdon. This makes sense. lemme adhere to this standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io/) or you could use ASP.NET in Visual Studio (if you have one installed) which has a drag-and-drop feature, but building a 'high-end' website is fully depended on what you could do. I would suggest that you create/build websites from scratch: text editor (I would suggest [Brackets.io](http://brackets.io/) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)) and exploring on [w3schools](http://w3schools.com) or [codeacademy](http://codeacademy.com).

Comment: Thx for suggesting Bootstrap Studio, I think so this could help me out. But only think is I have to purchase it to use it. anyways I will make still more R & D and will decide for a purchase. 
Also, I came across w3schools tutor but still I am looking for any easy method to build rather than using txt editor or PHP editor.
Just exploring the other ways and will finally decide which is a better way to go.

Comment: Glad I could help. But like I said, it would be a good practice to use text editors in building websites. It will help you grow more as you create. Depending on drag-and-drop software will not help you grow and learn more.